# Apache camel browse queue without polling it

Tags: java, logging, browser, apache-camel

I need to log my database with events on my ActiveMQ.
With logging I mean messages can't be consumed.

Is the folowwing thing possible

```
public class QueueRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure(){
 from("browse:activemq:KBC)
.process(new QueueProcessor());
}
}
```

Comment: To me it is not clear what you want to achieve. Please describe your use case in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

That camel route is event driven. I.e. it has to somehow poll events of that queue to know whats been dealt with.

I would, instead, go for copies to a queue used for logging. This can be done in two ways with ActiveMQ.

1. [Mirrored queues](http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html). That is - every queue has a mirror with all messages copied to it. You simply read of the mirror to do logging/monitoring.
2. [Virtual Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html). You can setup a Composite Queue that forwards the message to multiple queues (one for real usage and one for logging). However, this has to be done via config on all involved queues.
3. To allow easy wire-tapping, you can switch to topics. It's easy to tap of the messages by simply adding a subscriber. If you really need the queue semantics, you can use [Virtual Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) which is the best of the two worlds - topics with queues!